# Output userid when structure stored in an array

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, structure

I have the following array with a structure within each array (see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Excalibur/HgGf3/) for what the array looks like).

How do I loop over the array, then get the structure within the array to pull out the userid?  I keep getting errors with variations that I've tried.  The most common error I'm getting is:

```
Must be a valid structure or COM object
```

Here is the code I have to loop over the array and structure that is generating the error above (see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Excalibur/HgGf3/) for what the array looks like).

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(getTeamDetails)#" index="s">
    #s#) #getTeamDetails[s][uid]#<br>   
</cfloop>
```

Mark asked for some more code so I've included how I'm populating the array/structure:

```
<cfoutput query="getTeam">
    <cfset getTeamDetails[getTeam.currentrow] = StructNew()>
    <cfset a = StructInsert(getTeamDetails[getTeam.currentrow], "firstname", getTeam.firstname, 1)>
    <cfset a = StructInsert(getTeamDetails[getTeam.currentrow], "lastname", getTeam.lastname, 1)>
    <cfset a = StructInsert(getTeamDetails[getTeam.currentrow], "uid", getTeam.uid, 1)>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: What's in the variable "UID"?  Your "s" will contain an index of 1 to 3 and that is probably NOT your problem. We'll need to see more code to know how to help.

Comment: the UID contains the userid.  The jsfiddle has an example of what the uid contains.  I included 3 of the 30 records in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(getTeamDetails)#" index="s">
    #s#) #getTeamDetails[s].uid#<br>   
</cfloop>
```

I created your array and structure from scratch and loop through it to access the structkey you need to access.

```
<cfscript>
ThisArray = arrayNew(1);
for (i = 1; i lte 3; i=i+1) {
    ThisStruct = structNew();
    ThisStruct.UID = "123";
    arrayAppend(ThisArray, ThisStruct);
}
for (i = 1; i lte arrayLen(ThisArray); i=i+1) {
    ThisOutput = "#i#) #ThisArray[i].UID# <br>";
    writeOutput(ThisOutput); 
}
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#ThisArray#">
```

Comment: You almost had it.  There is a needed period after [s] and before the uid.  `<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(getTeamDetails)#" index="s">
    #s#) #getTeamDetails[s].uid#<br>   
</cfloop>`

Comment: there you go.  Thanks @evik-james